# Why is the function mapping the indices of an isonormal Gaussian process to its respective random variables linear?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, malliavin-calculus

First time approaching the book *The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics* by Nualart and I see

[image: Nualart book]

Why do these calculations show that the mapping $h \rightarrow W(h)$ is linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a random variable $X$ satisfies $E[X^2] = 0$, then $X=0$ with probability $1$. The calculation shows that
$$W(\lambda h + \mu g) - \lambda W(h) - \mu W(g) = 0$$
or equivalently that
$$W(\lambda h + \mu g) = \lambda W(h) + \mu W(g)$$
with probability $1$.